# how i use jquery internal in phonegap index.html?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

i just join phonegap, i want a built test application. i write some code index.html, it run on web browser properly. but in xcode. or simulator not runing. just check it. my code

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".class").click(function(){
if(a===0){
        $("#abc").css({"position":"absolute","height":"500px"});
    a=1;
}else
{    
    $("#abc").css({"position":"absolute","height":"50px"});
    a=0;
}
});

});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function kkk(){

alert("okey");
}


</script>


</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button id="abc" class="class" onclick="kkk()">Click me</button>
<button id="abd" style="position:absolute; left:250px;width:100px"> me</button>




</body>
</html>
```

any suggestion will appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use phonegap and listen to the deviceready call. then do your js inside the handler